# Custom grunt tasks are repeating themselves and not running sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm having trouble properly sequencing tasks in Grunt.

What I'm building has a lot of code built into it, so I'm going to simplify the code to show you what I'm struggling with. I have a folder with a bunch of files that start with a 4-digit ID number. Each ID has about 12 files with ~200MB of total JSON data.

I have a task that looks like this:

```
// Run data by ID
grunt.registerTask('run', 'Publish data for a single ID', function(id) {

   var done = this.async();

   // (1) Process data for that ID and store it into 6 huge arrays

   // (2) DB connection opened and each array is inserted
   //     into 6 different collections via mongoose

   grunt.log.ok('ID '+id+' has processed');

   db.close(), done();

});
```

This task works as it should. Depending on the ID's total file size, this task takes anywhere from 15-45 seconds per ID.

My next challenge is to take it a step further and use grunt.file.recurse() to find all of the IDs in the directory and then fire off subsequent "run" tasks for each id. without getting into grunt.file.recurse(), here is a basic example of how it would run 3 IDs:

```
// Run data
grunt.registerTask('runALL', 'Publish all data', function(id) {

  grunt.task.run(['run:0001','run:0002','run:0003']); // etc

});
```

When I fire the command "grunt runALL", the grunt log erroneously says...

```
>> ID 0001 has processed

>> ID 0001 has processed
>> ID 0002 has processed

>> ID 0001 has processed
>> ID 0002 has processed
>> ID 0003 has processed
```

So as you can see... every time it goes into another iteration, its starting from the beginning again. Instead, I want the tasks to run in sequence and have the result like...

```
>> ID 0001 has processed
>> ID 0002 has processed
>> ID 0003 has processed
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make each ID run only once from the "runALL" task? Thank you for any advice you can offer.